# How can i get a quaternion through my 1 axis gyroscope?

Tags: quaternions

My problem is, i have a 1 axis gyroscope and a 3 axis acellerometer in my device. I managed to get the quaternion through the accelerometer but i cant figure out how to do it with the gyroscope.

I want to be able to, through my gyroscope ( angular rate information) get a quaternion out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well since your gyroscope only has 1 axis it means that the 2 other orientation axis are fixed. Then you can get your one variable axis + 2 others in a euler angle and [transform it to a quaternion with this process](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/index.htm)

Comment: sorry i didn't understand, pardon my ignorance.
I have 1 angular rate value (in this case a float). Could you explain better how i turn this float into "Then you can get your one variable axis + 2 others in a euler angle"?